# After creating pandas data frame from csv, filtering results returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Description of the problem: After creating pandas data frame from a csv file, filtering result with loc() returns empty dataframe.

Goal: I have a csv file full of data, and I would to filter rows based on conditions.

This is the current code I am using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ss_scrape_centrs.csv')
print(df.loc[(df['m2'] > 60) & (df['Ist'] == 3) & (df['Dz_Cena'] > 150000)])
```

I get the following response:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Rajons, Dz_Vieta, Dz_Cena, Dz_Cenakvm, Dz_Links, m2, Ist]
Index: []
```

Comment: are you sure samples under these conditions exist in your dataframe ?

Comment: Drop the `.loc`, also as @YOLO said, are you sure these conditions exists, not only because of the original csv but of how the data is read by python? (For example if `DZ_Cena` being interpreted as string)